# C# unused Property crash my code

Tags: c#, oop

The Code prints different answer depending on debugging or not. What did i wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Feld feld = new Feld();
        feld.Setze = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(feld.Besetzt);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Feld
{
    public int figur;

    public bool Besetzt { get => (figur != 0) ? true : false; }
    public int Setze { set => figur = value; }
    public int Nehmen { get { int cur = figur; figur = 0; return cur; } }
}
```

If i delet the last Property it work's but why?

Comment: Please add your code to the question **as text**, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @fvu And even if the code was posted in the question we can't know where the problem is....

Comment: Rebuild your application maybe

Comment: @LudovicFeltz well, if it was text, we could try running it, so...

Comment: @MarcGravell You are right :)

Comment: I get `True` no matter how I run it... the code isn't the problem. Is it perhaps showing "build failed" at the bottom of the screen? perhaps because the exe is still running so it can't write the exe?

Comment: Do you have the variable `Nehmen` in the Watch window in Visual Studio?

Comment: i debug it with vs and if you take a look at the value of feld it's 5 and when i hover over a second time its 0.

Comment: @Shadow well, yeah! every time you read the property *it nukes itself*; that's what the code in `Nehmen` *says to do*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on the existing comments and answers: your `Nehmen` property *has nasty side-effects*:

```
public int Nehmen { get { int cur = figur; figur = 0; return cur; } }
```

every time the value is *read*, it **resets** itself to zero. This is a very bad idea - property `get` accessors should *not* have unexpected side-effects. Large parts of the tooling expect reading `Nehmen` to *not do that*, and the IDE / debugger will often try to help you understand your data by *querying the properties* to show you.

This means that when the debugger is trying to *help* you, it is actually resetting the values.

So: make `Nehmen` a *method*:

```
public int Nehmen()
{
    int cur = figur;
    figur = 0;
    return cur;
}
```

The system *expects* methods to have side-effects, so does not invoke them to "help" you.

The only valid side-effects of property `get` accessors is to invoke lazy-loading / initialization side effects.

Answer (score 2):

You must have the variable `Nehmen` in the Watch Window in Visual Studio... Or trying to access it in other way

Comment: and that's why one doesn't write properties with nasty side-effects! good spot